# (\d+) and ([0-9]+) htaccess rewrite not working on new server, works fine on old server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, regex

RewriteRule ^mp3/(\d+)/(.*)/$ download.php?id=$1 [L,NC]

is the specific rewrite rule I am trying to get working....it was working fine on my old server but now I am on a server with Apache 1.3.4.1 if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Apache 1.3.4.1 doesn't exist. Do you mean 1.3.41?

Comment: what kind of error you you have

Comment: You also did not specify what version the original server was.

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest Apache.  It might not solve the problem, but why fight bugs that might have been fixed by someone else.

Answer (score 3):

\d is not supported in Apache 1.3.x. Use [0-9] instead. (\d will work in Apache 2.)